# AWT GridBagLayout not working in different screen resolutions

Tags: java, user-interface, awt

I have a frame where the components are arranged using a GridBagLayout. My understanding about layouts is that if I use them they will automatically manage my components based on the screen resolution. My frame looks like the image below on my machine but when I run it on a different machine the layout gets messed up. Could anyone guide me with the right approach to fix this issue with different resolutions?

```
package com.shivam;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

public class TestFrame extends Frame implements WindowListener {
    Label qno, question;
    Checkbox opt1, opt2, opt3, opt4;
    CheckboxGroup groupoptions;
    Button next, submit;
    Image image;
    TestFrame() {
        setTitle("QuizApp - Quiz");
        setBackground(new Color(42, 20, 66));
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
        setLayout(gbl);
        qno = new Label("1");
        qno.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gc.gridy=0;
        gc.gridx=0;
        gbl.setConstraints(qno, gc);
        add(qno);

        question = new Label("What is the what of how do you do and when, explain with detailed derivation?");
        question.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 24));
        gc.gridy=0;
        gc.gridx=1;
        gc.ipadx = 500;
        gc.insets = new Insets(0,40,0,0);
        gc.gridwidth = 2;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbl.setConstraints(question, gc);
        add(question);
        addWindowListener(this);
        groupoptions = new CheckboxGroup();
        opt1 = new Checkbox("GuluGulu");
        opt1.setCheckboxGroup(groupoptions);
        opt1.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        gc.gridy=1;
        gc.gridx=1;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gc.ipadx = 150;
        gc.insets = new Insets(20,0,0,0);
        gbl.setConstraints(opt1, gc);
        add(opt1);

        opt2 = new Checkbox("Honululu");
        opt2.setCheckboxGroup(groupoptions);
        opt2.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        gc.gridy=2;
        gbl.setConstraints(opt2, gc);
        add(opt2);

        opt3 = new Checkbox("PewPew");
        opt3.setCheckboxGroup(groupoptions);
        opt3.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        gc.gridy=3;
        gbl.setConstraints(opt3, gc);
        add(opt3);

        opt4 = new Checkbox("MachuPichu");
        opt4.setCheckboxGroup(groupoptions);
        opt4.setFont(new Font("Dialog", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        gc.gridy=4;
        gbl.setConstraints(opt4, gc);
        add(opt4);

        next = new Button("Next");
        next.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        next.setBackground(new Color(30, 144, 255));
        next.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        next.setSize(100,50);
        gc.gridx = 0;
        gc.gridy = 5;
        gc.ipady = 15;
        gc.gridwidth =2;
        gc.insets = new Insets(50,0,0,0);
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
        gbl.setConstraints(next, gc);
        add(next);

        submit = new Button("Submit");
        submit.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 22));
        submit.setBackground(new Color(129, 131, 129));
        submit.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        submit.setSize(100,50);
        submit.setEnabled(false);
        gc.gridx = 1;
        gc.gridy = 5;
        gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        gbl.setConstraints(submit, gc);
        add(submit);
        setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("src/resources/boy.png");
        MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(this);
        tracker.addImage(image, 0);
        try {
            tracker.waitForID(0);
        } catch (InterruptedException ae) {
            System.out.println("Exception occurred while loading image...");
        }
        setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(image,950,300,null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        this.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e) {

    }
}
```

[image]

On a screen with different resolution.
[image]

Comment: *but when I run it on a different machine the layout gets messed up.* - no idea what "gets messed up" means. You also need an "after" image showing how it is messed up and explain what you expect to happen.

Comment: I have added a screenshot.

Comment: Post an [mre] to demonstrate the problem. Your question is about the layout of the frame, so all the quiz logic is irrelevant to the problem. We should be able to copy/paste/compile/test the code to see the described behaviour.

Comment: I have removed the quiz logic and updated the code segment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic answer is that you are not using layout managers effectively. You are:

1. using only a single layout manager
2. hardcoding spacing values between components
3. hardcoding the painting of the image

So when you move to a different resolution or frame size the layout manager doesn't adjust since you have so many hardcoded values.

For example:

```
gc.ipadx = 500;
```

A spacing of 500 on one resolution won't work on another.

```
g.drawImage(image,950,300,null);
```

Again, hardcoding the location assumes a given resolution. Also you should NOT override paint() of the Frame to paint the image. Instead I would suggest you override paint of a Canvas and then add the Canvas as a component to your frame.

Also, you should learn how to nest a Canvas with different layout managers. For example for your radio buttons I would create a Canvas with a GridLayout that displays the button is a single column.

Maybe for the buttons you create a buttons canvas with a BoxLayout and use "glue" between the two button so one is displayed on the left edge and one on the right edge.

Then when you add the components to the GridBagLayout you have in the first column:

1. the question label
2. the canvas of radio buttons
3. the canvas of buttons

In the second column you have the image

I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to learn the basics of each layout manger and how you might be able to nest them to achieve a dynamic layout.

Yes, the tutorial is from Swing, but layout managers work the same in both AWT and Swing.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I hardcoded those values because the layout manager wasn't placing them where I wanted them on screen, components were always on edges, with hardcoded values I was able to move them a little towards where I wanted them. Since layout manager isn't giving me flexibility to do that, If I follow your approach will I be able to customize alignments without hardcoding any values?

Comment: Well, there is always subtle hardcoding of values. You might use 5/10 pixels to put a gap between components when using a FlowLayout for example. But larger values like 500 show an improper usage of layout managers and you are trying to force a component so be is a certain location. When using a GridLayout you can specify a gap between each component. It  is only done once, not every time you add the compnent to the canvas so it is simpler to code and change if you ever decide you need a larger gap.